# Transfer Conv Layer's Weight from Keras to PyTorch

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

So I create this simple model in Keras:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
keras_weights = model.get_weights()
```

And I also create a similar model in PyTorch:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 3, kernel_size=3)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(2700, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = x.view(-1, 2700)
        x = self.fc(x) 
        return x # the softmax computed later
pt_model = Net()
```

I know the Keras parameter's shape is [in a different order than PyTorch](https://gist.github.com/chirag1992m/4c1f2cb27d7c138a4dc76aeddfe940c2). So this is the way I transfer Keras parameters to PyTorch:

```
for i, (n, p) in enumerate(pt_model.named_parameters()):
    with torch.no_grad():
        if 'conv' in n and 'weight' in n:
            p.copy_(torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(keras_weights[i], (3,2,0,1)))) # for conv layer's weight
        elif 'weight' in n:
            p.copy_(torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(keras_weights[i], (1,0)))) # for dense layer's weight
        else:
            p.copy_(torch.from_numpy(keras_weights[i]))
```

There is no "size mismatch error" so far. However, when I compared the result, it showed different results:

```
x = np.ones((1,32,32,3))/2 # for keras
y = torch.ones((1,3,32,32))/2 # for pytorch

pt_model.eval()
print(F.softmax(pt_model(y)))
print(model(x))

# output:
# [[0.1495, 0.0770, 0.0740, 0.0601, 0.1135, 0.1814, 0.1109, 0.0918, 0.0777, 0.0640]] # pytorch
# [[0.13737796 0.0906269  0.12652941 0.08460842 0.11374795 0.10845644 0.07447342 0.0781411   0.10338538 0.08265299]] # keras
```

But when I tried to remove the conv layer (the model is only a single dense layer), the transfer worked, and the result showed the same value (slightly different in precision). Can someone help me to find out what's the problem with the transfer process?

**Update**: Here I provide the MCVE in Colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iMarcjfU35i-XYaTA5FmISLWnaGlnr79?usp=sharing